# UnitTest middleware in Larave5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a small middle ware for which I would like to write a test for.. I would like to do two tests:

1. Mock role_id with 1; handle should return TRUE
2. Mock role_id with 2; handle should return FALSE

How can this be done?

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class RedirectIfNotAdminUser {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (Auth::user()->role_id != config('Roles.admin')) {
            return Redirect::action('Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

At the moment the test that I run as follows:

```
public function testIsAdminUser() {
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->make(['role_id' => '1']); 

    $this->be($user);

    $response = $this->action('GET', 'admin\DashboardController@index');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

I also had to add a line in the setup, without it $this->be() doesn't work

```
public function setUp() { 
    $this->refreshApplication();
}
```

Is their a better way of doing the test?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public function setUp()
{
    $this->redirectIfNotAdminUser = new App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdminUser;
}

public function testIsAdminUser()
{
    // create a $user object (using a factory or something else).
    // assuming $user has a property role_id = 1.
    $this->actingAs($user);

    // create a mock of $request and $next.
    $response = $this->redirectIfNotAdminUser->handle($request, $next);

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
}

public function testIsNotAdminUser()
{
    // create a $user object (using a factory or something else).
    // assuming $user has a property role_id = 2.
    $this->actingAs($user);

    // create a mock of $request and $next.
    $response = $this->redirectIfNotAdminUser->handle($request, $next);

    $this->assertEquals(302, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

I believe the middleware returns a response with a status code `200` if it's `OK` and `302` if not.

Remember, you'll be the one to create a `User` instance and have it logged in (using the `actingAs()` method) and you'll be the one to create mocks of `$request` and `$next` that would be passed to your middleware's `handle()` method.

Comment: hi. thanks for you response. I have played around and had minor issues with $this->actingAs and mocking $next due to it being closure, so I have come up with a slightly different test that can be seen in the the main threat.